# No valid responses from any peers

Tags: hyperledger

I am trying the tuna-network example in my local environment. Its working fine without any issues in local GUI palyground (http://localhost:8080/login) and the cloud environment.

Unfortunately, when I tried in the command line I am getting the error

> No valid responses from any peers

The commands I have used are below.

```
blrk@hyperledger:~/tuna-network$ composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile tuna-network@0.0.1.bna
✔ Installing business network. This may take a minute...
Successfully installed business network tuna-network, version 0.0.1

blrk@hyperledger:~/tuna-network$ composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin --networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --networkName tuna-network --networkVersion 0.0.1
Starting business network tuna-network at version 0.0.1

Processing these Network Admins:
userName: admin

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Unexpected response of 500. Payload was:
Command failed

composer network start --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --networkAdmin admin
--networkAdminEnrollSecret adminpw --networkName tuna-network --networkVersion
0.0.1
```

That should initialize the chaincode